# iPad initial setup join Wi-Fi by scanning QR code

Tags: ios, wifi, setup, setup-assistant, camera

Is it possible to configure things such that iPad gives me an option to open the Camera app to scan a QR code to connect to a Wi-Fi access point? Do note that the iPad will be enrolled into DEP and this is required during the initial setup.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) You can provision for joining desired Wi-Fi access point in your MDM solution.

Comment: uh, ok. I didn't come across that part. That would definitely work for the primary problem, but I let the question remain, because the feature would be neat to know anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to access the built-in Camera app before the initial setup is complete.

As the iPads in question will be configured via DEP, the appropriate approach would be to provision for your device to join the desired Wi-Fi access point(s) automatically via your MDM solution. When done, the iPad will automatically connect to the said Wi-Fi network if it is available, even during the initial setup.

Comment: I accepted the answer, since the root matter seems clear. however, since the devices are wifi only, the initial setup for wifi needs a manual entry for the ssid whatsoever, or can I pre fill a wifi before ordering DEP devices?